# How to crop a software bitmap in rectangular shape - UWP

Tags: c#, bitmap, uwp

I'am capturing a frame from running video and converting it to SoftwareBitmap for further purposes. Before that I want to crop that frame into a rectangular shape. How is it possible?

```
        var thumbnail = await GetThumbnailAsync(file,seek_position);
        StringBuilder ocr=null;
        InMemoryRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        await RandomAccessStream.CopyAsync(thumbnail, randomAccessStream);
        randomAccessStream.Seek(0);      
        SoftwareBitmap inputBitmap;
        BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(randomAccessStream);
        // Get the SoftwareBitmap representation of the file
        inputBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();
       //crop inputBitmap

  public async Task<IInputStream> GetThumbnailAsync(StorageFile file,int i)
    {
        //int duration_millisecond = i * 1000;
        var mediaClip = await MediaClip.CreateFromFileAsync(file);
        var mediaComposition = new MediaComposition();
        mediaComposition.Clips.Add(mediaClip);
        return await mediaComposition.GetThumbnailAsync(
        TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(i), 0, 0, VideoFramePrecision.NearestFrame);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GetSoftwareBitmapAsync` method of BitmapDecoder object has several overloaded methods. You could use `GetSoftwareBitmapAsync(BitmapPixelFormat, BitmapAlphaMode, BitmapTransform, ExifOrientationMode, ColorManagementMode)` method to crop the software bitmap. You just need to define a BitmapTransform object for it.

Please refer to the following code sample:

```
SoftwareBitmap inputBitmap;
BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(randomAccessStream);
// Get the SoftwareBitmap representation of the file
inputBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync(decoder.BitmapPixelFormat,BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,new BitmapTransform() {Bounds=new BitmapBounds() {X=100,Y=200,Width=200,Height=100 } },ExifOrientationMode.IgnoreExifOrientation,ColorManagementMode.DoNotColorManage);
```

You just need to specify a new `BitmapBounds` to its Bounds property.

Please note that, at this step, you have got a cropped software bitmap, but if you want to use it to initialize a `SoftwareBitmapSource` and make it show in `Image` control. You will get an exception "***SetBitmapAsync only supports SoftwareBitmap with positive width/height, bgra8 pixel format and pre-multiplied or no alpha***.". You need to use `SoftwareBitmap _softbitmap = SoftwareBitmap.Convert()` to make a new software bitmap like the following:

```
SoftwareBitmap _softbitmap = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(inputBitmap,BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);
var source = new SoftwareBitmapSource();
await source.SetBitmapAsync(_softbitmap);
image.Source = source; //image is a Image control
```